# Move a whole git repo from one account to another

Tags: git

I'm new to git. I have a git repository on repositoryhosting.com (it contains 3 branches) and I want to move it to assembla.com. How can I move the whole lot with code history and branches so that I end up with the same repository on a different git service provider?

Answer (score 4):

First, clone your old repository:

```
git clone git://old-repo-url
```

Then create a new remote pointing to the new repository:

```
git remote add new-repo-name git://new-repo-url
```

Now push to the new remote:

```
git push new-repo-name branch1:refs/heads/branch1
git push new-repo-name branch2:refs/heads/branch2
...
```

Push each branch you care about, and voila! A nicely copied repository.

Comment: Or `git push --all`.  `git clone --mirror` could help too.